# android mobile "ontouchstart"

Tags: android, mobile, touch-event

I create a var so the var isn't an ID. So can't I just call addeventlistener on the variable or do I have to getelementbyid?

```
var down_btn = new sjs.Image("invis.png",40,40).bottom().left().offset(40,0);

down_btn.addEventListener("ontouchstart",function(){
          lastspot=2;
          player.moveTo(player.x,player.y+14);
          player.setImage("player_down.png");
          player.stop(); 
      });
```

any help would be awesome thanks